# What is SlotSharingGroup in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

Reference : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/jobmanager/scheduler/SlotSharingGroup.html

Definition : "A slot sharing units define which different task (from different job vertices) can be deployed together within a slot."

Can somebody elaborate it more?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 11):

A slot defines a fixed slice of resources of a TaskManager. Every subtask (parallel instance of an operator) needs a slot in order to be executed.

Since not all operators are equally resource intensive, some of them need more memory or cpu cycles than others. In order to better utilize resources, Flink allows subtasks of different operators to be deployed into the same slot.

Which operators can be deployed into the same slot is controlled by the `SlotSharingGroup`. Tasks which share the same slot sharing group can be executed in the same slot and, thus, share resources. By default, all operators are assigned the same `SlotSharingGroup`.

More information about Flink's scheduling and internal architecture can be found [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/concepts/runtime.html#task-slots-and-resources) and [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/internals/job_scheduling.html).

Comment: when I set a slotSharingGroup on an operation, will it also apply to all subsequent operations ? Or do I need to repeat the directive all the way down ?

Comment: The slot sharing group resolution works the following: If the user specifies a group name for an operator, this is taken as is. If nothing is specified and the input operations all have the same group name then this name is taken. Otherwise, the default group is chosen.