# How can I specify that parts of my flink job run in different taskmanagers

Tags: flink-streaming

I have a cluster with several taskmanagers. Each taskmanager (1 taskslot per TM) is running a different breed of job.

I have a particular job consisting on stages, which runs in 1 taskmanager (there is no rebalancing, so the graph optimizer merges everything in the same thread) and I want their 3 operators to run in 3 different taskmanagers, how do I setup that?

Comment: It sounds like you may have an unusual/interesting use case. What makes you think this will perform better?

Comment: it is a case of very slow checkpointing (tried both aligned and unaligned barriers).
The UI shows some operators very busy, but not necessarily back-pressured.
Given that all the graph runs merged as one block, I though maybe splitting the different operators across multiple taskmanagers would allow the busy operator to enjoy the resources of a full TM

Comment: Are you unable to scale the job horizontally, by increasing the parallelism?

Comment: unfortunately, in this specific use case, there is no section we can keyBy or parallelize in spits (constraints of the ML model we fitting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanism you're looking for is [slot sharing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741695/what-is-slotsharinggroup-in-apache-flink). This will allow you to force each stage of your pipeline into its own slot.

Your application might perform better if instead you were to disable operator chaining (`env.disableOperatorChaining()` will force each pipeline stage into its own thread) and then run this job on a TM that uses 2 or 3 CPU cores per slot. With this configuration you'd be using shared memory for communication between the stages, rather than the network.